# How can I set a minimum width (in characters) for a TextView?

Tags: android, text, rendering

I've had a good search for this on here and can't find a solution.

I have a TextView in a RelativeLayout which contains an integer number.
The number will range between 1 and 99 - can anyone tell me how to size
 the TextView so that its width is always the width of the string "99"
 even if it only contains "1"?

I need this because the positions of the components to the right of this
 TextView depend on its width, so all are position depending on how many
 digits the TextView contains.

I don't mind if this is done in XML or code - I just want to avoid having
 to set the width of a TextView in pixels!

Thanks for any possible solutions; Please ask if I've missed out any
 important info!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

try this:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:minEms="2"
```

Comment: you may also want to add
android:gravity="center"

Comment: it doesn't work correct, width still much bigger, basically 5 ems == 10 characters

Answer (score 24):

Ems works if your font is monospace.  For proportional fonts, you want it the width of two '0's, not two 'm's.  You can fall back to TextPaint.measureText like so:

```
float measureText = zip.getPaint().measureText("00000");
zip.setWidth(zip.getPaddingLeft() + zip.getPaddingRight() + (int) measureText);
```

Comment: Works like magic! Thanks a lot for sharing this code snippet. :)

Comment: Setting ems did not work for me, but this did.
Thanks pforhan :)

Answer (score 5):

Best way is to use `TextPaint`. Here is a simple example:

```
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
textPaint.setTextSize(yourTextView.getTextSize());
yourTextView.setMinWidth((int) textPaint.measureText("-88.88"));
```

Do not forget to specify text size in your TextPaint object
In `measureText` enter longest possible string you're expecting to see (I've written "-88.88" assuming my text can handle positive or negative numbers below 100 with 2 digits after comma)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the getTextBounds() method in the Paint class.
Didn't try it myself tho.

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution, set typeface of your textview as Monospace.

```
android:typeface="monospace"
```