# Android. Text input not going to right side, left only

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, mobile

I have this code, and it gives me something like this when I type in it.

```xml
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bottomText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Enter bottom text"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minHeight="150dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

[image: Result]

For some rgeason the text does not fill the entire box, and only goes on the left side, the text should fill the whole box. Thanks

Comment: android:ems="10" restricts the size of your EditText. Remove it and it should work as expected

Comment: Your code works fine for me in a ``ConstraintLayout`` - you should probably post the rest of the XML file. ``ems`` is just a width measurement, ``match_parent`` should always override it as far as I know? But if the parent is some other container (where's that blue border coming from?) that could limit the size

Answer (score 2):

You must remove

```
android:ems="10"
```

because it prevents the text from extend to it's root layout width [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7053738/14647144) about ems.