# When should we use android:ems over android:textSize when specific font size for EditText?

Tags: android

There are 2 ways to specific text size in `EditText`

- `android:textSize`
- `android:ems`

Most of the time, I am using `android:textSize` in sp unit

I was wondering, in what situation, we should use `android:ems` ( I do understand the meaning of ems from [What is meant by Ems? (Android TextView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053738/what-is-meant-by-ems-android-textview) )

Answer (score 0):

> one em in a 16-point typeface is 16 points

em is more predefined while `textSize` using `sp` is specific. It depends on your use case.

Sidenote: You can also set an `EditText`'s text size by using `textAppearance`.

Answer (score 0):

You should very rarely use ems.  Ems doesn't scale.  It means your text is always a fixed height.  This makes your app difficult to read for people who have vision problems.  You should only use it if your app will absolutely not work correctly with scaled text and you don't care how that effects the disabled.