What is the meaning of "android:ems"? - In EditText
I am a new programmer and I came upon a line called android:ems="" (in the Edit Text part). What is it and how does it works? Is it similar to the android:ems="" for the TextView?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053738/what-is-meant-by-ems-android-textview
